# How to deploy parsey's cousins with tensorflow serving

Tags: tensorflow, syntaxnet, tensorflow-serving, parsey-mcparseface

Are there instructions or some documentation somewhere or could somebody describe how to deploy the models available as "Parsey's Cousins" (see https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/syntaxnet/universal.md) with SyntaxNet under Tensorflow Serving? Even deploying just Parsey is a rather complex undertaking that is not really documented anywhere, but how to do this for the additional 40 languages?

Comment: does this help?
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/syntaxnet/universal.md

Answer (score 2):

This pull request partially addresses your request, but it still has some issues: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/pull/250.

We do have some tentative plans to provide easier integration between SyntaxNet and Tensorflow Serving, but no precise timeline.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the benefit of anyone else who finds this question, after some digging around on GitHub, one can find the following issue started by Johann Petrak:

https://github.com/dsindex/syntaxnet/issues/7

> a model from parsey's cousin is not able to export by that patch due to version mismatch

So whilst some people have been able to modify syntaxnet so that it works with Tensorflow Serving, this seems to be at the cost of using a version which is not compatible with Parsey's Cousins.

Currently the only way to get Tensorflow Serving working with languages other than English is to use something like [dsindex's code](https://github.com/dsindex/syntaxnet/blob/master/README_api.md) and train your own models.